# Apache 2.4 and LDAP

Tags: apache, ldap

I had a server running RHEL 6.5 with httpd 2.2, and I had LDAP authentication for web pages working perfectly with this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/restricted>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted files"
  AuthBasicProvider file ldap
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/local_users
  AuthGroupFile /etc/httpd/local_groups

  AuthLDAPBindDN CN=bind,OU=Generic-Logon,OU=Generic,DC=example,DC=com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword lamepassword
  AuthLDAPURL ldaps://ldap.example.com:636/dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub

  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

  require group restricted
  require ldap-group CN=ug-employees,OU=Dept,OU=Dept-Groups,DC=example,DC=com
  require ldap-group CN=ug-others,OU=Dept,OU=Dept-Groups,DC=example,DC=com
</Directory>
```

Users were getting excessive 500 errors accessing the restricted pages, and some Googling tells me that going from httpd 2.2 to 2.4 could solve this. I installed a fresh server with RHEL 7 and httpd 2.4, and that exact same line. But now...

```
[~]$ sudo apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 426 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Unknown Authn provider: ldap
```

What's going on here? The RHEL 7 manual says that LDAP authentication is baked into httpd 2.4, and AFAICT, I'm following the instructions from apache.org. FWIW, I can't any LDAP modules in yum or installed in my /etc/httpd/modules.

Thoughts? I know I'm missing something tiny.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
` and `LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so`?

Comment: Neither of those two files exists in my /etc/httpd/modules directory. I'm trying to figure out how to get a hold of them; I'd prefer to use yum or rpm to make the install nice and clean.

Answer (score 9):

According to Redhat's support site you should run

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
# yum install mod_ldap -y
```

See: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/977573

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Debian / Ubuntu and came to this page because you're getting the error:

> Unknown Authn provider: ldap

then this command should fix it (prefix with `sudo` if not running as root):

```
a2enmod authnz_ldap
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Centos 7 or RHEL 7, this should do the trick:

```
sudo yum install -y mod_ldap
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but executing the command in this answer returns:

"No package mod_ldap available."

I am running RHEL 7.

Answer (score 3):

If Oracle Linux 7, this should get you there:

```
yum --enablerepo=ol7_optional_latest   install mod_ldap
```

Answer (score 2):

[These instructions on the Red Hat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html/1.2_Release_Notes/chap-Installation.html) explain how to enable the appropriate `yum` repositories to expose `mod_ldap`, as well as other packages on which it might depend or that may be useful in your situation.

Also, in short, this is what I had to do to get it working on RHEL 7:

```
---- Displays which repos are enabled/disabled
$ sudo yum repolist all

---- Enable these two repos to get mod_ldap and other things...
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```